# how to run app in background in power on with out show app screen?

Tags: android, startup

with this [How do I start my app on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-do-i-start-my-app-on-startup) post run app when devise power on success

but when devise run this show my main_activity

i want run app in background (Because i call a volley request with timer for check server in background )

my manifest.xml :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="other_class.CLASS_START_UP"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

my class start_up :

```
public class CLASS_START_UP extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

i use this post [Run volley request every 5 minutes in background android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259349/run-volley-request-every-5-minutes-in-background-android) to run volley request in timer

my timer code is :

```
 private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        get_start_info();

        // Repeat this the same runnable code block again another 2 seconds
        handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 10000);
    }
};
```

my problem is i dont want when devise turn on show main activity show to user (foreground) i want only run in background

i am sorry i am not good in English language

Answer (score 2):

Try This one

```
   <receiver android:name=".service.ShutdownReceiver"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

ShutdownReciver.java

```
  public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    Log.e("Brodcast Call","####");
    Toast.makeText(context, "service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //            context.startService(new Intent(context, 
    PowerButtonService.class));
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, PowerButtonService.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);


}

}
```